# Symfony omit filename for routing

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-2.5

I am pretty new to Symfony and just learning it. Even though Symfony's documentation has helped me with all of my concerns and answered all the questions I've had so far, I wasn't able to find the solution to this question regarding routing.

Whenever I access a page, I need to specify the front-controller in order to trigger the routing:

```
http://localhost/symfony/app_dev.php/test
```

What I want to do to clean up the URL even further is omitting the front-controller:

```
http://localhost/symfony/test
```

This might be a simple thing, but I haven't been able to find a single SO question or documentation page which describes me how to do it (if it's at all possible). I have tried renaming the front-controller to index.php, which unfortunately doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried just removing the app_dev.php from the URL? If you have mod_rewrite enabled and your .htaccess hasn't been changed then it should work pretty much straight out of the box. For more info see http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html#what-is-an-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your httpd.conf says allows overriding

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.localhost.com
  DocumentRoot "/Projects/YourProject/web"
  <Directory "/Projects/YourProject/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

you can use this web/.htacces

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]    ##### this is the part that you     should tweak, have the .htaccess point the request to app_dev.php, since the routing.yml is empty initially
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]        ##### this is the part that you should tweak, have the .htaccess point the request to app_dev.php, since the routing.yml is empty initially
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the startpage to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app_dev.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

be sure ifmodule is enabled; [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

so in your prod environment you replace app_dev.php with app.php

you may also want to have different parameters for each environment, the best to do this is to put it into .gitignore 
and create two files :

```
parameters.prod.yml
parameters.dev.yml
```

and depending on stage you create a parameters.yml file with a symbolic link in the same dir like :

```
ln -s parameters.dev.yml parameters.yml
```